# A question on long line

Tags: vector-bundles, cotangent-bundles

Assume that $M$ is the long line. Is $TM$, the tangent bundle, isomorphic to $T^{*}(M)$, the cotangent bundle?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No (for any differentiable structure on the long line, there are many). Since $TM$ is a line bundle, an isomorphism $TM\cong T^*M$ is necessarily symmetric, i.e. given by a global section of $\mathrm{Sym}^2T^*M$, locally of the form $f(t)dt^2$. Since $M$ is connected the form is either positive or negative, thus provides a riemannian metric, hence a distance, which does not exist on $M$.

Comment: The metric gives a local distance, but since the long line is not path-connected, the local distance doesn't compare two arbitrary points.

Comment: I don't get your point. It is well known that the long line does not admit a riemannian metric, see [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Long_line_(topology)).

Comment: Ah, I did not realize that even a very large "manifold" with a Riemannian metric could be topologically metrized.  I was thinking of the obvious definition where you measure the infimum length of piecewise-smooth paths between two points, as computed by arc length, and which obviously doesn't work for a non-path-connected space.

Comment: Is $T^{*}(M)$ trivial?

Comment: No, for the same reason.

Comment: do you mean :triviality of  cotangent bundle implies that M is metrizable? if so, why?

Comment: Triviality of the cotangent bundle implies triviality of the tangent bundle (its dual), hence $T M\cong T^*M$ and you can apply my answer.

Comment: Although this question is 3 years old, just a comment to one of the comments above: The Long Line IS path connected. Any two points are contained in a chart which is diffeomorphic to a unit interval. The 1-point compactification of the Long Line is NOT path connected but since this it not a manifold, it is not interesting.